# Add time stamp to file which has at least one row in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have list of files at a location ${POWERCENTER_FILE_DIR} .
The files consist of row header and values.

```
MART_Apple.csv
MART_SAMSUNG.csv
MART_SONY.csv
MART_BlackBerry.csv
```

Requirements:

1. select only those files which has atleast 1 row.
2. Add time stamp to the files which has at least 1 row.

For example:
If all the files except MART_BlackBerry.csv has atleast one row then my output files names should be

```
MART_Apple_20170811112807.csv
MART_SAMSUNG_20170811112807.csv
MART_SONY_20170811112807.csv
```

Code tried so far

```
#!/bin/ksh
infilename=${POWERCENTER_FILE_DIR}MART*.csv
echo File name is ${infilename}
if [ wc -l "$infilename"="0" ];
then
        RV=-1
        echo "input file name cannot be blank or *"
        exit $RV 
fi

current_timestamp=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
filename=`echo $infilename | cut -d"." -f1 `
sftpfilename=`echo $filename`_${current_timestamp}.csv

cp -p ${POWERCENTER_FILE_DIR}$infilename ${POWERCENTER_FILE_DIR}$sftpfilename

RV=$?
if [[ $RV -ne 0 ]];then
        echo Adding timestamp to ${POWERCENTER_FILE_DIR}$infilename failed ... Quitting
        echo Return Code $RV
        exit $RV
fi
```

Encountering errors like:

```
line 3: [: -l: binary operator expected
cp: target `MART_Apple_20170811121023.csv' is not a directory
failed ... Quitting
Return Code 1
```

to be frank, i am not able to apprehend the errors nor i am sure i am doing it right. Beginner in unix scripting.Can any experts guide me where to the correct way.

Comment: Tagged `bash` and using `ksh`? Huh?

Comment: `[ wc -l "$infilename"="0" ];` is wrong. Well, looks like you have to do some homework before you start scripting. For instance 1) where is the  where is the command substitution,2) have you checked the output of `wc -l`, if so 3) How would you filter those results to get what you want 4) what comparison are you doing here, interger or string 5) and so. Also [\[ **shellcheck** \]](http://shellcheck.net) is a great correction tool for wannabe bash scripters. Good luck. ;)

Comment: @sjsam thanks, corrected the tagging. 
Yes,i have made lot's of mistakes. wc =0 won't help in my case.
Thanks for introducing shellcheck it's good.

Comment: BTW, my answer is an off-the-shelf solution for you. You could accept it as the answer if it fit your needs. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to shell scripting there is rarely a single/one/correct way to accomplish the desired task.

Often times you may need to trade off between readability vs maintainability vs performance vs adhering-to-some-local-coding-standard vs shell-environment-availability (and I'm sure there are a few more trade offs). So, fwiw ...

---

From your requirement that you're only interested in files with at least 1 row, I read this to also mean that you're only interested in files with size > 0.

One simple ksh script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

# define list of files
filelist=${POWERCENTER_FILE_DIR}/MART*.csv

# grab current datetime stamp
dtstamp=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

# for each file in our list ...
for file in ${filelist}
do
    # each file should have ${POWERCENTER_FILE_DIR} as a prefix;
    # uncomment 'echo' line for debugging purposes to display
    # the contents of the ${file} variable:
    #echo "file=${file}"

    #   '-s <file>' => file exists and size is greater than 0
    # '! -s <file>' => file doesn't exist or size is equal to 0, eg, file is empty in our case
    #
    # if the file is empty, skip/continue to next file in loop
    if [ ! -s ${file} ]
    then
        continue
    fi

    # otherwise strip off the '.csv'
    filebase=${file%.csv}

    # copy our current file to a new file containing the datetime stamp;
    # keep in mind that each ${file} already contains the contents of the
    # ${POWERCENTER_FILE_DIR} variable as a prefix; uncomment 'echo' line
    # for debug purposes to see what the cp command looks like:

    #echo "cp command=cp ${file} ${filebase}.${dtstamp}.csv"
    cp ${file} ${filebase}.${dtstamp}.csv
done
```

---

A few good resources for learning ksh:

- [O'Reilly: Learning the Korn Shell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920545.do)
- [O'Reilly: Learning the Korn Shell, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001957.do) (includes the newer ksh93)
- at your UNIX/Linux command line: `man ksh`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using just `find`, `sh`, `mv`, `basename`, and `date`:

```
find ${POWERCENTER_FILE_DIR}MART*.csv ! -empty -execdir sh -c "mv {} \$(basename -s .csv {})_\$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).csv" \;
```

I recommend reading [Unix Power Tools](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003302.do) for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified script would be something like

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Note I'm using bash above, can't guarantee (but I hope) it would work in ksh too.
for file in ${POWERCENTER_FILE_DIR}/*.csv # Check Ref [1]
do
if [ "$( wc -l "$file" | grep -Eo '^[[:digit:]]+' )" -ne 0 ] # checking at least one row? Check Ref [2]
then
 mv "$file" "${file%.csv}$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S').csv" # Check Ref [3]
fi
done
```

---

**References**

[File Globbing <sup>[1]</sup>](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)
[Command Substitution <sup>[2]</sup>](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)
[Parameter Substitution <sup>[3]</sup>](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)